# AWS EBS gp3 volume support on Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ebs

I have a question regarding support of AWS `gp3` on Kubernetes.

AWS announced `gp3` EBS volume type which shows better performance than existing `gp2`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html.

But, from [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs), I could not see `gp3` support by Kubernetes. As I understand, Kubernetes does not support `gp3` for AWS yet.

Is my understanding correct or is there other documentation that I might have missed?

Answer (score 6):

The question refers to the EBS in-tree storage plugin, `kubernetes.io/aws-ebs`, not the CSI one, `ebs.csi.aws.com`, which already supports gp3 volumes.

According to [this](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1187), gp3 support will not be backported to the deprecated in-tree provisioner.

> We do not have any plans to backport gp3 support to the deprecated
> in-tree provisioner. Our focus right now is on getting the EBS CSI
> driver to 1.0 release in preparation for enabling the CSIMigration
> flag on EKS clusters.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS EBS CSI Driver [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/511dd1ce45658ea64b1bd701118f7cc13632a741/docs/README.md) says from driver version [0.8.0](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/0043b009e26fb08c7df3ee34629c695cf45dbd9a/CHANGELOG-0.x.md#v080) gp3 is supported and is the default volume type. But gp3 is not yet supported when you create AWS EKS nodes on AWS outposts as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-on-outposts.html). It seems the kubernetes docs is not updated with this information.

Comment: can you please explain the meaning of this statement: `But gp3 is not yet supported on AWS outposts`?

Comment: Updated the answer..it will work if you create kubernetes nodes on normal ec2 but not on outposts

Answer (score 1):

We need to manually install the CSI driver into the EKS cluster by using provided Helm chart/manifests.

The official helm chart would also create a StorageClass named ebs-csi whose type is gp3.

Chart link: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/tree/master/charts/aws-ebs-csi-driver